# Python requests to fill form

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using python requests to fill the form.

```
payload = {"name": 'TEST', 'XXXX': '12345' ,'YYYY':'EEEE','ZZZZ':''}

x=requests.post("https://example.com", data=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'),verify=False)
```

Its not submitting the form, the form has two buttons SAVE and CANCEL.

In my payload I havn't included anything related to the buttons, as what I know  is that submission of form is handled by post method.

following is the HTML code for that part

```
<div id="button_row_12" class="button_row form_pane">
<input type="submit" name="_form_action1" value="Save" class="button" onClick="this.form._form_action1.disabled=true;this.form._form_action.value='Save';this.form.submit();">

<input type="button" name="_form_action2" value="Cancel" class="button" onClick="this.form._form_action2.disabled=true;this.form._form_action.value='Cancel';this.form.submit();">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="edit" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="iscan">
<input type="hidden" name="_form_visited" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="_form_action" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also add the `_form_action` field to your payload to imitate the Javascript `onClick` event:

```
payload = {"name": 'TEST', 'XXXX': '12345' ,'YYYY':'EEEE','ZZZZ':'', '_form_action': 'Save'}
```

Comment: The payload example is not the actual code you are using. Please post the actual one. You should also include the hidden inputs, did you?

Comment: Selcuk thanks after adding hidden parameters it worked. Thank you so much for the help